# Invalid Binary Error (The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app) after App Store submission

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We tried to submit a new build to iTunesConnect for updating an existing application. It is a quick patch for fixing one server url.

We changed two files: REST.plist for updating one server url and app_info.plist for updating the bundleShoreVersion String from 4.0.0 to 4.0.1 and BundleVersion from 4000000 to 4000001.

The 4.0.0 version was submitted three weeks ago without any issue.

However, we got rejected with Invalid Binary with 4.0.1 version and following email was sent to us:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "xxxxx". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple
>   app.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: For search engine indexing purposes this problem can also manifest with a slightly different wording: “The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken”

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is explained right here:

> The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app.

This is likely a new automated check, and that's why your previous versions went through with no problems before.

It's saying that your app is using a display name (the name below the icon on the homescreen) that an app made by Apple uses - for example, if the label said "Mail", then you could expect it to be rejected for this reason.

Change your app name to something Apple doesn't use in their apps.

Comment: Thanks @Undo for your quick reply. We have our app in appStore for more than a year, without any issue. We do notice some other apps are using same BundleDisplayName as us now, but not the Apps from Apple. We will try to contact with iTunesConnect to find out whose app should be treated as legacy app to keep the displayName.

Comment: @jxyiliu Here's a complete list of apps developed by Apple: https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/apple/id284417353?mt=12, for reference. Are you sure your app name doesn't conflict with one of these?

Comment: Truly appreciated your help, @Undo. It turns out our app display name might be conflicting with one of Apple newer released app. We will wait official response from iTunes Provider Support Team/DTS to find out what should be the next step.

Comment: Display name dose't matter in this case, even apple dose't validate too. I have faced similar issue. Pls let me know if found solution, If found by me so will defiantly share it.

Comment: I had been using display Name "Calc HD" since 2011, with regular updates several times a year, and now in 2018 I get this error. Currently trying all variations of display names to find something free. Not sure if it's the display name OR the bundle name (which contains my company name so it's hard to duplicate unless someone copied it)

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this issue, note that the values for *both* of these fields must be unique in your `Info.plist` file:

- **Bundle display name** (`CFBundleDisplayName`)

  - *displayed below icon on home screen*
- **Bundle name** (`CFBundleName`)

  - *defaults to `PRODUCT_NAME`, used internally, e.g. in filename like `MyApp.app`*

That is, your `CFBundleDisplayName` can be as unique as you want, but if your `CFBundleName` isn't, your upload will continue to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the name like fitness its most common name try with different one. It's saying that your app is using a display name 
you can resolve this issue by

1:     Changing the ***app display*** name
                     **OR**
2:     Change Target and scheme name.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was related to the app name that was the same as a app native system.
Ex .: Safari

Change the name and build again